# Gradient colour linea on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I'm plotng 3D data with matplotlib in python. The data simulate a brownian motion and its unclear on which Z is each point.

I would like to get a gradient colour on the graph line for exaple the higest value of z with red and the lowest with blue having a gradient between.

The matplot code I'm using is:

```
fig_b = plt.figure()
ax_b = plt.axes(projection="3d")

ax_b.set_xlabel('X Axes')
ax_b.set_ylabel('Y Axes')
ax_b.set_zlabel('Z Axes')

ax_b.plot3D(df_brow.x_i, df_brow.y_i, df_brow.z_i)

plt.show()
```

And i'm getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK3y6.png

Thank you